# How to draw multiple UIBezierPath with different colors in a UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, uibezierpath

I would like to draw multiple UIBezierPath in a UIView with different stroke and fill color.

Here is the code

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    [[UIColor grayColor] setFill]; 
    [[UIColor greenColor] setStroke];

    UIBezierPath *aPath = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init]; 
    [aPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(227,34.25)];
    [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(298.25,34.75)];
    [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(298.5,82.5)];
    [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(251,83)];
    [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(251,67.5)];
    [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(227.25,66.75)];   
    [aPath closePath]; 
    aPath.lineWidth = 2;
    [aPath fill]; 
    [aPath stroke];

    UIBezierPath *aPath2 = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
    [aPath2 moveToPoint:CGPointMake(251.25,90.5)];
    [aPath2 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(250.75,83.25)];
    [aPath2 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(298.5,83)];
    [aPath2 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(298.5,90.25)];
    [aPath2 closePath];
    aPath2.lineWidth = 2;
    [aPath2 fill]; 
    [aPath2 stroke];
    [paths addObject:aPath2];
```

The problem is that the stroke and the fill color are set on the current context.
Is it possible to draw different UIBezierPath with different colors in the same CGContextRef?

Or I have to draw each UIBezierPath in separate UIView?

Answer (score 24):

You should add

```
[desiredStrokeColor setStroke];
[desiredFillColor setFill];
```

indicating that these are the new colors that have to used further on in this context. You should do this before every time you call a

```
[aNewPath fill];
[aNewPath stroke];
```

so that the paths be drawn with those colors.

*No need to use a new view for each bezier path.*

Comment: Ok, thank you. Now if I want to change the fill and stroke color after the shapes are draw, how can i do? For example, lets image I hit a certain shape, how can I change his color?

Comment: You will have to maintain a mutable array of colors one for each path. You should change the color for that particular path and then call `setNeedsDisplay` on the view as it will invoke the `drawRect:` method.

Comment: Ok, thank you again. Maybee you could help me in my other question regarding the same subject here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432770/how-to-draw-and-interact-with-uibezierpath

Comment: How can I change the shape color outside the drawrect method? And if I call setNeedsDisplay, my view will be reinitialed no? Thank you

Comment: @iMacX: Since you still seem to be active on this site, the answer to your question is that you need to create a new class that stores a bezier path, a fill color and a stroke color.  Store an array of these, and you can change the color at any time, to be retrieved when drawing.  What do you mean be 'reinitialed'?  `setNeedsDisplay` causes your view to be cleared and redrawn (using `drawRect`, nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 8):

use this

```
int count = 0;
for(UIBezierpath *_paths in pathArray)
{
   UIColor *_color = [delegate1.colorArray objectAtIndex:q];
   [_color setStroke];
   [_path strokeWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0]; 
   count++;
}
```

In touch began store your paths and colors in two arrays and use them in drawrect like above.

Answer (score 5):

Just define a UIColor *setStroke; in .h file and set this strokeColor object before you call `[myPath strokeWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];`

```
 - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
    {
        [strokeColor setStroke]; // this method will choose the color from the receiver color object (in this case this object is :strokeColor)
        for(UIBezierPath *_path in pathArray)
            [myPath strokeWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
    }

    #pragma mark - Touch Methods
    -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        myPath=[[UIBezierPath alloc]init];
        myPath.lineWidth = currentSliderValue;

        UITouch *mytouch=[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
        [myPath moveToPoint:[mytouch locationInView:self]];
        [pathArray addObject:myPath];
    }
    -(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        UITouch *mytouch=[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
        [myPath addLineToPoint:[mytouch locationInView:self]];
        [self setNeedsDisplay];

    }
```

Comment: What is pathArray ?

Comment: Collection of UIBezierPath Objects .. @Abha